# Is there a name for this type of differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, bessel-functions

So I'm dealing with this type of differential equation:
$$x^2y^{\prime\prime}+xy^{\prime}-(k^2x^2+1)y=0$$
where k is a positive real number. Now, this looks similar to the Modified Bessel equation, but searching along those lines didn't help. So, does this equation have a name, and can it be solved?

Comment: what does WolframAlpha say?

Comment: Change variable $x=\pm ikt$ and you will go back to Bessel differential equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $\mathrm k=0$, the equation is [Cauchy-Euler equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Euler_equation). For $\mathrm k\neq0$ let $\mathrm{u=kx}$.

$$\mathrm{
{dy\over dx}=k{dy\over du},\quad
{d^2y\over dx^2}=k^2{d^2y\over du^2}
}$$
So our equation becomes
$$\mathrm{
u^2{d^2y\over du^2}+u{dy\over du}-(u^2+1)y=0
}$$
which is [modified Bessel equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselDifferentialEquation.html). Therefore the required solution is
$$\mathrm{
y=c_1I_1\left({kx}\right)+c_2K_1\left({kx}\right)
}$$

> Generalization

The substitution $\mathrm{u={2\over n}\sqrt{b}x^{n\over2}}$ turns 
$$\mathrm{
x^2y''+xy'-(bx^n+c)y=0
}$$
into a modified Bessel equation where $\mathrm b>0$.

Comment: Any chance you mean $y = c_1 I_1(kx) + c_2 K_1(kx)$?

Comment: @okrzysik Thanks for the correction :)

Comment: No problem! Also to guarantee the solution is real (assuming $k$ is real), I think it really should be written as $y = c_1 I_1(|k|x) + c_2 K_1(|k|x)$. Because $k$ can of course be negative.

Comment: @okrzysik I considered that but in that case we'll restrict ourselves to $x<0$, I pretty much left the solution as described in the Wolfram article :)

Comment: OK sure I understand. I just figured I'd mention it because typically one doesn't consider real Bessel functions with $x \in \mathbb R^- $. Also it's quite possible that $k < 0$.

Comment: Oh, so it does ultimately become a modified Bessel equation. Thanks. And there's no need to worry about k being negative, as I already mentioned it's positive in the question.

Comment: @DanielHarper it does indeed, I admit I missed that information when I skimmed over your question! After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/).

Comment: Aah, my bad. For what it's worth, I did upvote it :)